# Font displays in text field very small

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextfield

I have this class, and I am trying to display a custom font in a text field, but but when I run it the font is super tiny like `2px` tiny. If i just run `font = new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 24);` it displays just fine at the right font size.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Small]

Here is what it looks like when I only use `font = new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 24);`

[image: Large]

What is causing the small text box with a custom font?

```
public class Search extends JTextField{

    public Search(int width){
        super(width);

        Font font;
        String filename = "/media/fonts/SourceCodePro-Light.ttf";

        try{
            InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
            font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            font = font.deriveFont(24);
        }catch(FontFormatException | IOException ex){
            font = new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 24);
        }

        this.setFont(font);

    }
}
```

Comment: JTextField(int) for intial preferred size accepted by all LayoutManager (excl. NullLayout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`font.deriveFont` has two overloaded forms that can be quite similar. The one taking `int` sets the font style, the one taking `float` sets the font size. YOu are invoking the `int` version instead of the `float` version. Change `24` to `24.0f`, and it will work

Comment: Wow! I was copying from another class I had and I even had a float there. Thanks for that!